# How to install clang in custom location from SVN, making it recognize c++ standard library, on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clang++

I try to compile and use clang from svn trunk. I basically try to follow the directions [here](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html):

```
svn co -q http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
svn co -q http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk llvm/tools/clang
svn co -q http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/clang-tools-extra/trunk llvm/tools/clang/tools/extra
svn co -q http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk llvm/projects/compiler-rt

mkdir llvm_build_release
cd llvm_build_release
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/usr/local -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=host ../llvm
make -j12
make install
```

Above, I configure clang to be installed in the custom location `~/usr/local` since I want to be able to play with it without changing my default environment.

I then create a simple test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
  std::cout << "Hello world\n"; 
  return 0; 
}
```

and try to compile it:

```
~/usr/local/bin/clang++ test.cpp -o test
```

but get the error message:

```
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

(using the system version of clang, the same compilation works fine).

If I manually enter which standard library to use, it does work

```
~/usr/local/bin/clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -I/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ -L/usr/lib test.cpp -o test
```

The question is: How do I configure, compile and install clang from source so that I *do* *not* have to enter these standard library settings, but instead can just enter the ordinary `~/usr/local/bin/clang++ test.cpp -o test`? I have macports installed, with its version of the standard libraries and the include files, if that helps.

Comment: What does `clang++ -v test.cpp` say about what directories it looks at?

Comment: Is there any reason why you could not use MacPorts' clang-3.6 port? It currently is based on SVN revision 222672, lagging only a hundred commits, and you could bump it by altering the Portfile.

Comment: What compiler have you used to build clang (see cmake logs)? Can you check what std library this compiler use libcxx or libstdcxx?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just got a computer crash. Will answer when I'm back in business.

Comment: @Paul Guyot: Initially, clang-3.6 was lagging a few months and I needed a newer version where a certain parsing bug was fixed. I eventually filed macports request to update clang-3.6, which was kindly fixed ( https://trac.macports.org/ticket/45998 ). It would still be interesting to know how to make it work though, just for kicks... ;-)